# I want to generate sequential ID in PHP, unique but not random

Tags: php

I want to generate sequential ID in PHP e.g: EmployeeID, CustomerID etc. We use 'static' variable in Java, Class variable in Python to generate sequential ID which hold the value of last increment. Same thing I want to do in PHP. How is it possible? I find that 'STATIC' keyword in PHP do not have exact same use as in Java.

Here is my Java Code:

```java
class DemoClass{
   private static int counter=1000;
   public DemoClass(){
     System.out.println("Object: " + ++this.counter);
   }
}
public class Demo {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    DemoClass a = new DemoClass();
    DemoClass b = new DemoClass();
    DemoClass c = new DemoClass();
  }
}
```

I want to do the same thing in PHP. The following is the code in which I am doing wrong. Please help I have searched a lot but didn't find a suitable solution to this problem.

Here is my PHP Code:

```php
class Employee{
private $name, $address;
private $empid;
private STATIC $counter = 1000;

public function __construct($name, $address) {
     $this->name = $name;
     $this->address = $address;
     $this->empid = ++$this->counter;
 }
public function displayDetail() {
    echo "Employee Name: " . $this->name."<br>";
    echo "Employee Address: " . $this->address."<br>";
    echo "Employee ID: " . $this->empid;
  }
}

$emp = new Employee("Indranil Das", "421-Nabapally");
$emp1 = new Employee("Ronty Das", "422-Nabapally");
$emp->displayDetail();
$emp1->displayDetail();
```

This code isn't giving me the result what I wanted.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: Maybe remove STATIC here like this : `private $counter=1000;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, you can't access `static` class properties in object context. Instead of `$this`, you need to use `self` or `static` keyword, or the class name, coupled with `::` operator instead of `->`.

So, in your example, it's enough to change this line:

```
$this->empid = ++$this->counter;
```

to any of the following:

```
$this->empid = ++self::$counter;
$this->empid = ++static::$counter;
$this->empid = ++Employee::$counter;
```

`self` refers to a property of the current class. `static` refers to the first class in hierarchy where the property/method was defined. And the class name refers to the specific class.

Even though they all work the same in your case, `self` would be my pick in this example as it's the simplest one.

You can read more about static properties and methods in PHP in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).

Comment: Thanks. Actually I am new in PHP. This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php):

> Static properties cannot be accessed through the object using the arrow operator ->.

You can try doing

```
Employee::counter
```

to access the variable.